# How can one reconcile moral objection to wage slavery with the societial need for money?

Tags: ethics

If, within the framework of modern society, individuals depend on employment for survival, then how can one survive without breaking either their moral aversion to wage slavery or their moral aversion to moving their financial burdens onto others?

Thinkers such as Alan Watts or Terence McKenna have said that by following one's passion, one will find a way to make money. This makes sense to me, but many passions require an initial financial investment, such as attending graduate school.

Edit: Let me be clear, I'm looking for an answer for how to morally earn income and also how to move into such a position. I'm not looking for specific personal advice, but something that can be broadly applied to individuals. There are, of course, changes society could implement, such as universal basic income, but I'm seeking answers for the individual.

Comment: mendicant? lottery? doing something worthwhile?

Comment: Mendicancy moves the financial burden onto others.

Comment: self sufficient allotment with solar panels (donations are voluntary)

Comment: ... require an initial financial investment. Are you being serious? Your answers feel like trolling.

Comment: if *you're* serious you can look into the legality of living in a tent on common land and foraging for food (please don't do this). though you'd have to invest in a tent

Comment: [dumpster diving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dumpster_diving) and [homelessness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homelessness) would be the easiest answer. but seriously, please do NOT do this. not trolling, just not particularly serious about the question. you could try editing it to ask not for practical life advice

Comment: Wage slavery is bad enough, but imagine loading a pile of debt on top if it. I would be cautious about graduate school in today's world. Of course, this is all fact sensitive and you are better able to judge the facts which apply to your case.

Comment: @Gordon Actually I already have a massive student debt from my (financially) useless BSc. (I love what I learned at Uni & am a better person for it, but it seems financially dubious have actually found it harder to get a job since the degree.) So, recently I've been looking at moving to Europe for the free education.   Also, I *did* live in the woods for a month. It was amazing, but by November it got very cold and the water table dropped. Anyway, I ask this question not only for my benefit. I've run across many people who object to wage slavery, but have yet to hear a good solution.

Comment: Perhaps for the benefit of others: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wage_slavery

Comment: @RubelliteFae ah ok, sorry i was being naive. i don't see what you're asking, really. do some horrible care job for a few years, which means that you have the money to pursue a dream job, and have helped other people with their wage slavery etc.. or join an anarchist collective that doesn't just put a different emphasis on your problem, but seeks a grand solution. or write a best seller (there's no easy way to escape being working class)

Comment: After a comparison of your question, the answers, and the back-and-forth comments, it seems to me that most people are talking past each other. It might be that nobody understood the original question. I suggest another revision of the question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is a tough situation out there right now, we have an appearance of prosperity in the West which I think is hollow right now, it's fake. I would try to move inch by inch toward your goal. For instance, near me there is a natural history museum with a gift shop, I would take a job in the gift shop even with a pay cut to get a real job with a museum. You get the idea. There may be no such opportunities near you. But try every way you can to inch toward your dream, and good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The need for money is part of an existing social contract.  If you do need money, you have signed onto that contract.  You cannot be both within and outside the contract.  You need to set it aside entirely if you find its central tenets morally objectionable.

Money is not what you need.  What you need is a means of using your own attributes to support yourself.  If you want to morally disconnect from capitalism, that cannot involve money, since the value of money is clearly embedded in the system as a whole.

There are people who have taken this seriously and established a parallel social contract that insulates a sense of value based upon some other criterion from the need for money.  Communities like Ammana and Oneida, various tax-resisting Quaker Meetings during the Vietnam War, and the Shaker communities are historical examples.  A living example is the [Rainbow Family of Living Light.](https://www.welcomehome.org/main.html)

Such communities do not use money among themselves.  To manage this, they have to maintain a buffer between themselves and the economic community.  They usually institutionalize this buffer in the form of 'sovereign' land in unincorporated areas that is never allowed to have a monetary value assigned to it.  It is too far from public services to involve real estate tax, and it is either free of claim because it is hereditary and has not been sold for an extended period, or it is kept in an endless limbo of mortgage that is never allowed to build equity, so it is insulated from the income tax.  It is held in common and not passed down, so it avoids inheritance, which is the other point land that is not sold might be assigned monetary value and have taxes extracted.

This freezes this part of the means of production outside the capitalist system.  Those who hold this land may or may not allow you to join them on the assumption you will find away to contribute to the welfare of the community as a whole and that will offset the work involved in maintaining the insulation from capitalism.

Since the rest of our social contract is tied to taxes, this involves leaving the legal system and having some alternative means of government, that you may or may not find adequate, logical or fair.  So to some degree there is a risk of a more genuine form of slavery.  But you are generally free to leave with nothing and return to the capitalist system through charitable institutions.

Comment: This was not the kind of answer I was expecting, but it is the most accurate solution. I have heard of these communities, but it hadn't occurred to me as a solution to this quandary.

Answer (score 5):

> If... individuals depend on employment for survival, then how can one
>   survive without breaking either their moral aversion to wage slavery
>   or their moral aversion to moving their financial burdens onto others?

The premise that employment equals a type of slavery restricts the possible roads to survival. To remain moral, a person would have to (1) find employment which is not slavery or (2) find a source of wealth which does not involve shifting a personal burden onto someone else.

My suggestion is as follows. First, isolate that aspect of employment that makes it similar to slavery. Then, organize a business, commune, or other association that produces wealth, but drops the morally offensive aspect of employment.

Given the assumption that opens the question, that is as far as I can take an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the question.

Deciding that working *for someone* is slavery may be your opinion, but it is a subjective opinion, and not necessarily indicative of objective reality.

People have been doing work in order to survive for as long as there have been people, and at no point during that time did these people get to dictate *what* they did anywhere outside of the system they were born into.

In other words, as human societies have progressed, the nature of work has taken on slowly evolving concrete forms that make up the reality of the population. At any point in time, there can be no other way.

Within that context, I don't see a reason why 'ethics' or 'ideals' should enter anywhere into the equation. Following your passion is a great concept, but if it leads you into a place within the system you live in where you can't find work or support yourself, what have you gained?

I'd think when it comes to work one should first attempt to understand the market in which they live, and then further how they would best like to use it to their advantage.

Comment: As with the answer below, you have misrepresented the term wage slavery, it is not, and never has been, used to define the fact that people have to work for their sustenance, please at least read the Wikipedia link already provided by the OP before answering. The term 'Wage Slavery' refers to the concept that employers (or the marketplace) get to dictate both the nature of the works that must be done and the volume of work that must be done in order to sustain ourselves, rather than the physical laws of biology. You may disagree, but please at least give the philosophy some respect.

Comment: If it were legal to live a hunting & gathering lifestyle I would have done that ages ago. Still, some people have decided to subsist on urban foraging and is an option to consider. But, yes, like Isaacson the question isn't "How does one survive without working?" I enjoy working, particularly when it is work that I'm good at.

Comment: Respectfully, I don't think I have misrepresented the term wage slavery, I understand exactly what it's intent is. My point is: 'wage slavery' is a subjective method of defining our current situation, not an objective one, and put in another light what people face could also be seen as physical reality. There can be no other way. It's like a North American native in 5000 BC asking how they can subsist without hunting. In our times there may be ways to actually persist without wages, but the term 'wage slavery' doesn't seem particularly helpful here.

Comment: Philosophy.SE is not a place for simply listing your opinions, your view that "... there can be no other way" is simply stated as fact without any argument to back it up. Whilst you're perfectly entitled to hold such opinions, an answer on this site is not the place to espouse them. If you wish to demonstrate that 'wage slavery' is just an unavoidable reality, then either construct or reference arguments against things like minimum wages, restricted working hours/contracts, common land movements, communism... etc. Then your answer (albeit tangential) will meet the requirements of this site.

Comment: @Isaacson the overwhelming brunt of philosophy references I could add here would amount to pseudo-scentific thought, just as the philosophy in the original question itself is pseudo-scentific. So my 'thought' is just as valid as anything that some guy has managed to get published with no basis in scientific reality.

If you're going to restrict answers to references in journal articles or books, then you have to take into account the veracity of the questions themselves, and you're also limiting yourself to published thought.

Answer (score 2):

You have proposed two moral principles: 
1) You don't want to be a "wage slave" (as you define it).
2) You don't want to live on the resources of others.
There are two assumptions a) working for yourself is not readily available and b) you want to survive. In the context of the assumptions, the two moral principles are, on their face, inconsistent -- a common human problem. We usually try to live with the inconsistency, using one principle at one time and the other at another depending on the situation or our emotional state.
     Alternatively, you could choose one and jettison the other. In doing so you will have to compare their value. Which principle does the most good? Which one can you live with? Under what circumstances would you be able to change your mind? 
      As is typical, I have answered a question with more questions.

Comment: jobermark's answer shows that principles 1 & 2 do not have an XOR relationship. I.e., there is at least one solution that involves neither wage slavery or burdening others. By the by, I actually didn't define wage slave. Cicero was the first to state the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into [squatting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squatting), and how you might find food and otherwise stay healthy in such an environment.

[image]

I imagine you'll find some share your sympathies, for what it's worth.

Which you seem to have defined conservatively enough to not be self contradictory. Not sure what Watts would say about your dilemma, but I don't think I see how making money from your passion is any different to investing money, perhaps a loan, to pursue your passion, given that what you earn would then be supporting you to pursue it, and you e.g. pay back the loan. I don't see how loans are slavery if they're paid back with work you love.

Which was the reason for my facetiousness in the comments: if you're just saying you don't want to do certain forms of work but must be self sufficient this is not really a philosophical question.

Comment: For example a painter who works as a waiter to support himself is spending time and energy working a job to barely get by and has little time to hone his craft. But, a Renaissance painter lucky enough to have a patron can spend as much time as he likes on his passion. A painter who takes out a loan can as well, assuming he can pay back the loan by selling his paintings, but of this there is no certainty. Alternatively, a painter in an economy with UBI has none of the above worries about starvation, debt, or allegiance to a single patron.

Answer (score 1):

> If, within the framework of modern society, individuals depend on employment for survival, then how can one survive without breaking either their moral aversion to wage slavery or their moral aversion to moving their financial burdens onto others?

People who work for a wage aren't slaves and slavery is not an apt metaphor. A person must have food, shelter etc. to survive. Nobody is obliged to provide you with these goods. If you maintain otherwise, then you are saying the person who can provide those goods should be forced to work to provide you with them: he is your slave. The person who can provide those goods should do so only if he has been persuaded to do so by argument, or by receiving goods he wants in exchange.

One of the options for obtaining goods that you can exchange for food and shelter is that you can agree to do stuff another person asks you to do in exchange for money to be paid in a short time - a wage. In order to pay a wage somebody has to gather the resources necessary to pay that wage and do without them for the period required to produce something that can be sold.

Some people say the employee and employer have unequal bargaining power and that this is unfair in some way. A person looking for wage work can consider an offer and negotiate or reject the offer. He need not accept the first figure that the employer proposes. There are books on salary negotiation if you don't think that's an option. If an employee wasn't providing value nobody would want to hire him. If the employee fails to think about this issue and look for information about how to use it, that's the employee's responsibility. The employer is not obligated to do this for the employee. There are other options, like starting a small business, or a large business. Promoting the idea that employers have power over employees is a vicious lie. That lie demonises employers and claims that employees are not moral agents who can make choices about what they value and how they want to obtain it.

A commenter below complains about employers treating employees as a means to an end. An employer does not treat an employee like a cog in a machine because the employee can resign. The employer would then have to find a replacement. However, the employer won't pay someone to watch cat videos on youtube. The employer will demand and *should* demand that the employee will do something of value to him to get paid.

The current system has many defects, like lots of burdensome govt regulation that stop people from starting some kinds of businesses, but that's govt slavery not wage slavery. If you complain about wage slavery, then you have a beef with the laws of physics since they don't require cooked roast chickens to fly into your mouth with no effort on your part.

It would be a good idea to learn some political economy. See "Time will run back" by Hazlitt for an explanation of the relevant economic issues that you might find interesting:

https://mises.org/library/time-will-run-back-0

A short explanation of the moral issues can be found in "The virtue of selfishness" by Ayn Rand.

Comment: You have misunderstood the term 'Wage Slavery' which has been used frequently throughout history to describe the unequal bargaining power between the business owner and the worker, thus rendering the worker unable to anything but accept whatever term the business owner wishes to offer. It has nothing to do with requiring "...cooked roast chickens to fly into your mouth with no effort on your part", it is about treating humans not mere means to an end, but as ends in their own right, that humans deserve more dignity than their economic value as parts in a machine.

Comment: I have altered my answer to address your misunderstandings of the economic and moral issues involved.

Comment: Torture cannot be made morally acceptable simply by allowing the victim to choose which torturer they wish to submit to. Likewise, choice of employment has no bearing on the argument. As the ownership of land is supported by force of arms, the option to not be employed at all, but instead fend for oneself, is removed, by force. This, to some people, is a form of slavery. I'm well aware of the moral and economic arguments, it does neither side any service to simply misrepresent them.

Comment: Getting resources from people voluntarily isn't torture. If you feel bad about having to provide value to get stuff, you are irrational. You can't take land from other people who already own it. You can go looking for unowned land. That's not any kind of slavery. It's just a policy that you are not allowed to force other people to provide you with stuff for free. Its a policy to prevent slavery.

Comment: I didn't say getting resources from people was torture, I said that giving someone a choice of torturer did not affect the morality of torture, likewise giving someone a choice of employment does not affect the morality of employment. Nor did I say anything about taking land from people who already own it, all land was unowned until someone staked a claim to it **by force**, successive governments have defended that claim **by force**, therefore the situation we are currently in whereby one does not have the choice to fend for oneself is one imposed on us **by force**, hence the comparison.

Comment: It's not about feeling bad about having to provide value. It's that the value I can provide is unequal to the financial compensation available. But, the employer has all the bargaining power because I have to eat to live. Since this is the case with all employer/employee relationships, the pay floor is constantly lowered. _De facto_ this is done by keeping wages stagnant (or increasing them more slowly) as the money supply increases. This drives the cost of living up by lowering the value of the dollar. Prices rise, borrowing increases. Repeat.

Comment: You aren't answering the question as asked. ① One can't "negotiate the salary" of an hourly paying job. They'll hire someone who *is* willing to be paid less than their value. ② "Other options, like starting a small business, or a large business" are *not* options as they "require an initial financial investment" which the question indicated not everyone has access to. ③  A proper answer should be presume the ethos of the question. This isn't a debate site. So please answer the question which is asked rather than attempting to promote your preferred ethical framework.

Comment: You can negotiate the salary of any job. Sometimes a question has a load of false assumptions that makes the question invalid and the question has to be critised and replaced. There's a name for this kind of activity it's called philosophy. The barrier to entry for many businesses is extremely low. If you have a computer and you can type you can run a business. Promoting the idea that you can't start a business is factually wrong and grossly immoral. Also, you don't understand basic economics. Try looking up subjective theory of value.

Comment: The assumptions are not 'false' or 'invalid' they are just ones which you do not agree with, and for the last time 'Wage Slavery' is not about choice it is about employers and the market dictating **what it is one must do to earn a living**, the fact that you could start a business with just a computer has no bearing on the matter, some people might not want to spend their day sat at a computer. It is the overall nature of the **total range** of jobs on offer that wage slavery refers to, it has **nothing whatsoever** to do with the choices *within* that range.

Comment: If I disagree with an assumption then I think it is false. That's what disagreement means. The market doesn't dictate what you have to do to live. The laws of physics dictate the requirements for staying alive. The market provides a means for correcting errors about how people are using resources to stay alive, and for fulfilling other preferences. If you choose to ignore the means it provides to live a better life rather than learn about them, then you will have a bad time and it will be your fault.

Comment: -1: I don't usually down-vote but this answer appears to be mostly opinion despite specious references to Rand & Mises.

Comment: @MoziburUllah All of the answers are opinion and involve a moral evaluation of wage labour. I am explicit about this and I insist that my evaluation is correct while everyone else fudges and that having the correct evaluation is important. You are used to people fudging and acting as if their ideas don't really matter and you have come to respect and expect such conduct. This is a very serious defect in your worldview.

Comment: @alanf "Given X, what Y's are possible?" doesn't mean you get to change X. Dissent to the given isn't pertinent. I made no assertion that X is true. I asked a question with regards to the assumption of X being true.

Comment: X in this case is both false and grossly immoral. It is not a suitable starting point for any intellectually or morally serious investigation. It should be rejected root and branch.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that a small but significant minority of people do not fit your description. There are people who live entirely on the income of inherited or invested wealth. There are people who are genuinely self-employed and running a profitable business. There are people who are content to live on the provision of the state or charity. As for the rest of us, I recognise the metaphor of wage slavery. Also, pension slavery for those unfortunate enough not to save enough for old age. All workers spend but some also save. Prudent investment can result in a step change in fortune. So we all have options, but some have very few and are not helped to realise them. Notwithstanding what you said about specific measures, I favour universal basic income, micro-finance, and mutual and co-operative companies.